# How to run Java code in sublime Text 2?

Tags: java, batch-file, sublimetext2

I used to write and run python code in sublime, but now I want to learn Java so I want to know how to run Java code in sublime. 
I read some solutions online but they didn't completely make sense. 
I sort of get that I first need to create a .sh file that includes the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
javac %1.java
if  errorlevel  1  goto  error
echo [OK, running... ]
java %1
goto  end
:error
echo  [Compile was unsuccessful]
goto  end
:end
```

But I'm confused where should I save the above file? In the sublime folder?

And then I need to create another file .java that includes:

```
{
   "cmd": ["javacr.bat", "$file_base_name" ],
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "working_dir": "${file_path}",
   "selector": "source.java"
}
```

But I also need to save this file somewhere and I don't know what is Java.sublime-build as they said? And what is the PATH?

I really appreciate if someone could explain to me step by step how to achieve these. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use a proper IDE such as [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/)?  They're both free, will handle all of the "complexity" out of the box, and will help with other aspects of working with Java such as debugging, jar packaging, etc.

Comment: @blazetopher for the love of god don't use eclipse, intellij ftw!

Comment: @NimChimpsky - LOL, I don't use eclipse, never been a fan.  I'm still a NB guy mostly because I've been using it forever...I've contemplated a move to intellij a few times, maybe I'll get that back on my radar!

Comment: In sublime edit 3 , there is a build system menu, select javaC then select build. But rather use and IDE like IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Add JDK to your path.

Save your MyProg.java somewhere.

Execute `javac myProg.java` to compile to bytcode.

Then `java myProg` to run the actual program.

Alternatively download a **decent** ide (intellij or Netbeans) it will help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to use java in sublime:

First Install JDK

In sublime go to Tools -> Build System -> New Build System
put below code:

```
 { 
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name", "&&", "java" ,"$file_base_name"], 
    "selector": "source.java",
     "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)", "path" : 
    "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.2\\bin\\", 
     "shell":true
     }
```

Save it with any name (like, Runjava.sublime-build)

Note: In path give whatever java version present in your system at these location "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\"

Then, create a folder with three files in it B.java(Main java file), input.txt, output.txt.
Go to Tools -> Build System -> Select Runjava

put below code in B.java file:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            System.setIn(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));

            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")));

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Error");

        }
        
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

    }
}
```

give input in input.txt file

see output in ouput.txt file

Answer (score 0):

After correctly Installing Java on your machine (setting the JDK's path).
-Write you java program then save it where ever you want.
-Compile your program with javac command(in terminal), this will generate a .class file if your compilation went without errors(**javac name_of_your_program.java**).
-Run the generated file with the "java" command and that's all you need.
**PATH** is an environment variable, it will contain the path to your JDK to tell your system where to find the appropriate Java command.

.
My advice is simply to work with an IDE (there are many of them), It's much more simple and provide you with many tools.